# Postfwd "ignoring empty counter" for sasl_username rcpt rule -what does this mean?

Tags: postfix, postfwd

I'm trying to rate limit per user based on sasl_username using postfwd.   (FWIW, I was using Cluebringer and this worked, but it feels clunky).

I have a rule

```
id=RULEDEFAULTSASL
  sasl_username=~/^(\S+)$/
  action=rcpt(sasl_username/200/7200/REJECT only 200 recipients per 2 hours for $$sasl_username)
```

Postfix is logging the following

> postfwd3/policy[13604]: [RULES] rule=1, id=RULEDEFAULTSASL,
> client=xxx.domain.com[10.1.1.1],
> user=user@example.com, sender=user@exmaple.com,
> recipient=user@example.org, helo=<[10.2.2.2]>,
> proto=ESMTP, state=RCPT, ignoring empty counter

- Can someone advise what **ignoring empty counter** means?

(Initially I thought that the counter was not working, however when I run

```
postfwd3 -vv --dumpcache -p 10040 -f /etc/postfix/postfwd.cf
```

It does indeed appear to show entried with updated counter values as expected.

Comment: This "ignoring empty counter" continues to show up even when the counter values for that entry are > 0